# Running Spark EC2 scripts with IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, amazon-iam

I am trying to run Spark EC2 scripts to launch a cluster under an IAM role which my user under my root account can assume.

According to [this JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10532), we can now specify `--profile` when running Spark EC2 scripts, and the [comments on the pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/8696#issuecomment-139701773) say that the `--profile` option refers to what I believe as the AWSCLI profile.

When I run the scripts as

```
ec2/spark-ec2 -k key-name -i key-name.pem -s 1 --profile myprofile --instance-type=t2.medium launch test-cluster
```

I get

```
Profile "myprofile" not found!
```

However, running

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --profile myprofile
```

works as intended, leading my to think the IAM role was specified correctly in the `~/.aws/config` (I don't think you specify IAM roles in the `~/.aws/credentials`).

However, when I add a test profile to the `~/.aws/credentials` as

```
[foobar]
aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxxx
aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxx
```

Spark finds the `foobar` profile. However, after adding

```
[foobar]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::12345:role/MY_ROLE
aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxxx
aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxx
```

Spark finds the `foobar` profile, but it does not correctly log into the IAM role. I get

```
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidKeyPair.NotFound</Code><Message>The key pair 'key-name' does not exist</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>fcebd475-a895-4a5b-9a29-9783fd6b7f3d</RequestID></Response>
```

This is because the key pair `key-name` does not exist under my user, but it does exist under the IAM role I need to assume. This tells me Spark is not properly logging into the IAM role.

---

My `~/.aws/config`:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxx
aws_access_key_id = xxxxx

[profile myprofile]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::12345:role/MY_ROLE
source_profile = default
```

My `~/.aws/credentials`:

```
[default]
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxx
aws_access_key_id = xxxxx
```

---

*Side note- also tried:*

Assuming the role manually with

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::12345:role/MY_ROLE --role-session-name temp-session
```

then exporting the `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`, and `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` to the environment variables.
I then ran the EC2 scripts without any profile specified and got

```
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 401 Unauthorized
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>AuthFailure</Code><Message>AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>11402f6e-074c-478c-84c1-11fb92ad0bff</RequestID></Response>
```

---

*Side note- also tried:*

According to [this JIRA on Spark scripts with IAM roles](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/6962), we can specify `--instance-profile-name` (*is an instance profile the only way of using an IAM role this way? ie.. would I have to ask our admin for IAM list/create permissions to launch a cluster with an IAM role?*). I have tried using `arn:aws:iam::12345:role/MY_ROLE` and `MY_ROLE` but get

```
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code><Message>Value (arn:aws:iam::12345:role/MY_ROLE) for parameter iamInstanceProfile.name is invalid. Invalid IAM Instance Profile name</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>ffeffef9-acad-4a34-a925-31f6b5bbbb3e</RequestID></Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed assigning a role to an ec2 instance by providing the '--instance-profile-name' parameter with the spark-ec2 script which you can pass a profile name.

Inside the instance make sure to run

```
sudo yum update
```

Look also at my question:
[Running Spark EC2 scripts with IAM role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893992/running-spark-ec2-scripts-with-iam-role)

Good Luck