# Assign Role to AWS EC2 Cluster via spark script

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I'm not able to assign a role to a ec2 cluster via the spark script spark/ec2/spark-ec2. I use the following command to start the cluster:
where myprofile is a testing profile with sufficient permissions.

```
./spark-ec2 -k <key name> -i <aws .pem file> -s 2  -r eu-west-1 launch mycluster --instance-type=m4.large --instance-profile-name=myprofile
```

I can see the instances in the ec2 console where they also have the correct role assigned.
I then proceed to ssh into the master instance with:

```
./spark-ec2 -k <key name>  -i <aws .pem file> login mycluster
```

and with

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/myprofile
```

I can view my temporal security key, access key and a security token. However, running

```
aws s3 list-buckets
```

returns

```
"Message": "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."
```

Retrieving the keys via the curl command and pass them to boto does not work either, giving a '403 permission denied'..

Am I missing something?

Please see this very similar question below. But as I am not allowed to comment there and I neither have the answer to it I made a new question. Maybe someone could comment to that person with a link to my question. Thanks.

[Running Spark EC2 scripts with IAM role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893992/running-spark-ec2-scripts-with-iam-role)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had this problem for 3 days and now I solved directly after posting the question... do:

```
sudo yum update
```

will update the aws cli and after that roles seems to work.
I can even do in python:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
conn = S3Connection()
bucket = conn.get_bucket('my_bucket')
keys = bucket.list()
```